# In Android - "Invalid public key passed" Error in live

Tags: payment-gateway, flutterwave

I have integrated Flutterwave in my Android application. In sandbox the payment is working fine. I changed the sandbox to live and have updated the live public and secret keys.

But while checking the payment using my live card, it shows the error:

```
Invalid public key passed
```

Can any one help me?